# Is it alright to not award a bounty?

Tags: discussion, bounty, etiquette

Background: I was asking a question about [Wireless LTSP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223879/is-wireless-ltsp-possible), and while I received two answers that seem like they might work, I have no way of testing them right now (but I should a little bit later).  I know you shouldn't ask theoretical questions on askubuntu (or at least, I don't *think* you're supposed to), but I needed to know the answer to my question to determine if it was even worthwhile pursuing LTSP.  I originally put the bounty on because my question had been lost in the depths of askubuntu, and I used the bounty to draw a little more attention to it.

Question: Is it alright to not award a bounty, even if they're good answers? And if it is, would it be polite to award a new bounty later once I have determined the best answer?

I feel kinda bad since I don't have any good way right now to determine the better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to *not* award a bounty.  If you don't do it manually, it will go to the answer with the most votes when it expires.  This is a good thing, I mean, it would defeat the point of bounties if they didn't get awarded and just 'hung in mid air' after they expired.

So, since you don't know which answer is right, the one with the most votes is what *other*  people think the correct, and therefor probably is.

Just remember to come back and accept the right answer after you've tested them
.

Comment: Well, except that neither of them have any votes on them, (I assume since not many people know much about using LTSP wirelessly) so I don't know which one to give the bounty to.

Comment: The question is very difficult, which is why good answers are hard, there's only so many ways you can say "yeah, that's impossible". I've added an answer as well since I have some experience with ltsp.